# MySQL: float convert large value in to exponent

Tags: mysql

In my db table I have a field float where I store cost of a project if I insert cost **4559006** is saved like **4.55901e+006** and when I perform mathematics operation on it it produces errors.

How could I fix it?

Comment: Are You sure You store it as float and not as string type (char/varchar/text)? 4.55901e+0006 is just the way of representing large numbers, arithmetic operations should work fine.

Comment: What data-type is that field in where you have inserted that value? A `FLOAT`? If so, try using `DECIMAL`

Comment: What kind of errors do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point types are not suitable for precise calculations

Use `decimal(15,2)`

15 is the number of significant digits including scale 2. You can increase that up to 65 if needed.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html